# Using auth0 SDK in react native app

Tags: react-native, auth0

I want to use auth0 SDK in my react native app, but it seems it's tied to the browser environment using `window` or `document`.

Is there a node / react native port of this SDK?

I want to use APIs such as `renewIdToken`, `refreshToken`, `getDelegationToken`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I created a React Native (Node.js as well in the future) port of Auth0.js myself here.

https://github.com/joonhocho/auth0-react-native

Currently, it's a Work in Progress.

Please help with PRs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Auth0 has official documentations for React Native with [iOS](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native-mobile/react-native-ios/) and [Android](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native-mobile/react-native-android/).